# why server returns "Bad request" using sfml socket http-get?

Tags: sockets, sfml, http-get

I'm using sfml network to make my own download manager. But i'm not familiar with http Get request.

I'm using TcpSocket.

Here are my code in c++

```
int main() {
```

// ----- The client ----- 
// Create a socket and connect it to 192.168.0.100 on port 80

```
 sf::TcpSocket socket;

 socket.connect("192.168.0.100", 80);
```

//Send a message to the connected host

```
std::string message = "GET /projects/ads/index.php HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.0.100\r\n\r\n";
socket.send(message.c_str(), message.size());
```

// Receive an answer from the server

```
 char buffer[1024]; std::size_t received = 0;
 socket.receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer), received);
 std::cout << "The server said: " << buffer << std::endl;
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;

 }
```

It shows me an HTML content and in the body, appered a message "Bad request!"

I think the error's coming from the message i sent before i receive the contents. There's  something wrong in it but what?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i just needed to use HTTP/1.0 version in the message instead of HTTP/1.1 so it works perfectly now ;P